# How can I paste text from dataframe rows, keeping only unique values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text, merge, unique

I have a dataframe where each row represents a person, and the columns represent the names they have gone by. Some of the values are NAs or are duplicates. The data looks like the dataframe immediately below.

| Name | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Tom | Thomas | Tom | Tommy |
| Jim | NA | James | NA | Jimmy |
| Dave | Dave | David | NA | Davey |
| Tim | NA | Timothy | Tim | Timmy |
| Rob | Rob | NA | Rob | Robby |
| Sam | NA | NA | Sam | NA |

I would like to combine the unique names from each row and put them into a new column, where each name only occurs once. I know i can use the paste function to produce a column where all the text values appear like this:

| Name | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | unique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Tom | Thomas | NA | Tommy | Tom, Tom, Thomas, NA, Tommy |

but I don't want the same text to appear multiple times in the unique column.
How can I combine the row data such that each name only occurs once in the new $unique cell?

| Name | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | unique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Tom | Thomas | Tom | Tommy | Tom, Thomas, Tommy |
| Jim | NA | James | NA | Jimmy | Jim, James, Jimmy |
| Dave | Dave | David | NA | Davey | Dave, David, Davey |
| Tim | NA | Timothy | Tim | Timmy | Tim, Timothy, Timmy |
| Rob | Rob | NA | Rob | Robby | Rob, Robert, Robby |
| Sam | NA | NA | Sam | NA | Sam |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 rowwise %>% 
  mutate(unique = toString(unique(na.omit(c_across(everything()))))) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  Name  Name1 Name2   Name3 Name4 unique             
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>              
1 Tom   Tom   Thomas  Tom   Tommy Tom, Thomas, Tommy 
2 Jim   <NA>  James   <NA>  Jimmy Jim, James, Jimmy  
3 Dave  Dave  David   <NA>  Davey Dave, David, Davey 
4 Tim   <NA>  Timothy Tim   Timmy Tim, Timothy, Timmy
5 Rob   Rob   <NA>    Rob   Robby Rob, Robby         
6 Sam   <NA>  <NA>    Sam   <NA>  Sam
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply`ing `unique` row-wise, `na.omit` and collapse `toString`.

```
transform(dat, unique=apply(dat, 1, \(x) toString(na.omit(unique(x)))))
#   Name Name1   Name2 Name3 Name4              unique
# 1  Tom   Tom  Thomas   Tom Tommy  Tom, Thomas, Tommy
# 2  Jim  <NA>   James  <NA> Jimmy   Jim, James, Jimmy
# 3 Dave  Dave   David  <NA> Davey  Dave, David, Davey
# 4  Tim  <NA> Timothy   Tim Timmy Tim, Timothy, Timmy
# 5  Rob   Rob    <NA>   Rob Robby          Rob, Robby
# 6  Sam  <NA>    <NA>   Sam  <NA>                 Sam
```

You could additionally implement a `sort` if you like.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = c("Tom", "Jim", "Dave", "Tim", "Rob", "Sam"
), Name1 = c("Tom", NA, "Dave", NA, "Rob", NA), Name2 = c("Thomas", 
"James", "David", "Timothy", NA, NA), Name3 = c("Tom", NA, NA, 
"Tim", "Rob", "Sam"), Name4 = c("Tommy", "Jimmy", "Davey", "Timmy", 
"Robby", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df%>%
 rowid_to_column()%>%
 left_join(pivot_longer(.,-rowid)%>%
 group_by(rowid)%>%    
 summarise(value=toString(na.omit(unique(value))), .groups = 'drop'))
  rowid Name Name1   Name2 Name3 Name4               value
1     1  Tom   Tom  Thomas   Tom Tommy  Tom, Thomas, Tommy
2     2  Jim  <NA>   James  <NA> Jimmy   Jim, James, Jimmy
3     3 Dave  Dave   David  <NA> Davey  Dave, David, Davey
4     4  Tim  <NA> Timothy   Tim Timmy Tim, Timothy, Timmy
5     5  Rob   Rob    <NA>   Rob Robby          Rob, Robby
6     6  Sam  <NA>    <NA>   Sam  <NA>                 Sam
```